# MySQL IF statement part of two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to say something like this with a MySQL statement:

```
IF 
  table1.fieldA = "SearchText" AND 
  table2.fieldB = "FindThis" 
THEN 
  table2.fieldC = "Y"
```

I'm pretty sure there's got to be a `JOIN` in there somewhere but I'm new to this so I'm not sure how to write it.

Comment: Thank you, @bernie for formatting my statement. I hope that helps someone clarify what I need.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
SELECT yourfields
FROM table1 join table2 on table1.ID= table2.ID
WHERE CASE WHEN table1.fieldA = "SearchText" AND table2.fieldB = "FindThis" THEN table2.fieldC ELSE '' END = "Y"
```

you may or may not need the `ELSE ''` with MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear your requirement. For a joined table update;

```
Update t2
Set t2.fieldC = "Y"
from table2 t2 join table1 t1
           on t2.colM = t1.colN --join with appropriate columns
where t1.fieldA = "SearchText" and  t2.fieldB = "FindThis" 
      and t2.fieldC is null -- if you need to update only nulls (as per comment)
```

Comment: I'm not trying to _get_ 'Y', I'm trying to add the letter Y to table2.fieldC based on the 'IF' scenario.

Comment: If that means putting something in a field where there is nothing now, then -- Yes -- an update.

Comment: Well, you need to clarify. if it is a new row of data then it is an insert, if just filedC is null/empty then it is an update.

Comment: There is an additional column called 'TRUEHOLD' on table2 to hold this information. If the scenario above is TRUE, then put a Y in this new column. I apologize if I'm not being clear.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was creating a `VIEW` for each set of tables. I then did an `UPDATE` against the two columns (since they're in the same table now), like so:

```
UPDATE view_table 
SET truehold = CONCAT('Y', truehold) 
WHERE columnA ='BLAH' AND columnB='12345'
```

Then, when building my query, I could say:

```
WHERE truehold NOT LIKE 'Y%'
```

because there were some duplicates, which made the column say 'YY' or 'YYY'.

Anyhow, thank you all for getting me down the right path.